# Unity button prefab with different code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, static, unity-game-engine

I've created a button prefab in Unity. I use the OnMouseUpAsButton function to handle the click. I want different behavior for every instance of the prefab.

What I did so far, is that the prefab has a `public string message` member, which is the name of a function to run, when the user clicks the button. I run this message with the StartCoroutine function, but this is not for static functions, and I want my functions to be static.

I've found this [article](http://benbeagley.com/2013/10/14/calling-a-static-ienumerator-in-unity/), to run a static function, but it seems an expensive operation to me, I don't want to call it every time, the user clicks a button. What is the least expensive way to achieve this solution?

Comment: Get the associated game object (for instance using Find and the associated message string used also as the object's tag) and use a non-static function. It sounds like you want the static function only because it's easier to call (no need to have an object reference) but that won't get you very far.

Comment: Give them Id's and work from there. Or try using the [sendmessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) function. Or follow the NGUI style of doing things. And publicly assign a individual script on each ui button, doing whatever it should do/

Comment: sendMessage solved the problem, can you add an answer so I can accept it